# How to force ValidatePrincipal to be called on AuthenticatedUsers even for [AllowAnonymous] actions?

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-3.1, cookie-authentication, anonymous-users

I am using cookie authentication on a new ASP.NET CORE 3.1 project.

I have a controller action that is used by both guests as well as authenticated users. Because of that, it is decorated with the `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

The behavior of the action is slightly different if the user is authenticated so I use `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to check that out and if true, I then retrieve the principal's claims in order to perform a database update.

The problem that I have is that because the action allow's anonymous, the `OnValidatePrincipal` event of the cookie authentication scheme is not called to make sure that the current claims are up to date.

This means that even if the `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` flag is true, I cannot rely on the claims that come with it because they are not validated in this case.

First of all, this seems to me like a problem. Second, does anyone know if there is a way around that ? Some ways to force the `OnValidatePrincipal` event to be called as soon as the `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` flag is true no matter if the action requires authorization or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a dummy controller method that requires authorization and call it when `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` flag is true.